# DocuSign API - List Templates Doesn't Include Tabs Details

Tags: docusignapi

I'm making a GET request to get all Templates:

`GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates`

and according to the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/list) I should be able to specify `tabs` as one of the options for the `include` parameter, e.g.:

`GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates?include=documents,recipients,tabs`

When I include the `tabs` string I get the following error:

```
    {
      "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER", 
      "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. include values must be either 'folders', 'advanced_templates', 'recipients', 'documents, 'custom_fields', 'powerforms', 'favorite_template_status' or 'notifications'"
    }
```

I'm after the tabs details for each Template in the list of results but it appears that `tabs` is not a valid option here despite it being specified in the docs.

Not sure if the docs are out of date here and if this is no longer possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a documentation error - the API call to get the list of templates was never able to include the list of tabs. In order to do so, you will need to make an additional call directly to the template ID. That call does support the tabs parameter.